# SQL UPDATE-with-Join in MonetDB

Tags: sql, join, syntax, sql-update, monetdb

I'm using MonetDB 11.33.3 (April 2019 release). I want to update records in some table,  using corresponding values from another table.

Specifically, and for example, suppose `table1` has columns `col1`, `col3` and `table2` has columns `col2`, `col4`. Assume that there's an injective map from the values of `table1.col3` to `table2.col4` (so that when we equi-join with these columns we get at most one match). I want to set `table1.col1` to the corresponding `table2.col3` value - from the single matching record in `table2` (using the equi-join I just mentioned).

Here is my attempted query:

```
WITH t2 AS (SELECT * FROM table2)
UPDATE 
table1
SET
col1 = t2.col2
WHERE
col3 = t2.col4
;
```

this gives me:

```
SELECT: identifier 'col1' unknown
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this particular error, and thus don't understand what I've gotten wrong or how to fix the query.

Comment: 11.33.3 is very old.  A lot of things have been changed, fixed and optimised.  Please consider upgrading to the latest release 11.39.11.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET col1 = (SELECT t2.col2 FROM table2 t2 WHERE table1.col3 = t2.col4)
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE table1.col3 = t2.col4);
```

Comment: So, there's no use for the `WITH` clause then? Also, if I need to set more fields, I'll be replicating the inner query many many times.

Comment: @einpoklum . . . You can use with to define `table2`, but you still need to reference the CTE in a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug that has been fixed. I tried on Nov2019 release, and I didn't get the error.